# how to execute scoverage report with optional parameters using maven command

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, scoverage

how can I add this [optional parameters](http://scoverage.github.io/scoverage-maven-plugin/1.3.0/check-mojo.html) (e.g `minimumCoverage` ) with [scoverage-maven-plugin](https://github.com/scoverage/scoverage-maven-plugin) .
when calling

```
mvn scoverage:check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `pom.xml` file, e.g.:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
            <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <minimumCoverage>50</minimumCoverage>
                <failOnMinimumCoverage>true</failOnMinimumCoverage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

or add to command line e.g.:

```
mvn scoverage:check -Dscoverage.minimumCoverage=50 -Dscoverage.failOnMinimumCoverage=true
```

or mix both methods. Command line parameters override those defined in `pom.xml` file.

Comment: If we added this maven option into a jenkins job , isn't it expected to fail? `-Dscoverage.minimumCoverage=50 -Dscoverage.failOnMinimumCoverage=true` . I tried different numbers like 50, 100, 120 and still the job succeeds. Please help.